# Use of ILaunchConfigurationMigrationDelegate

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I do not understand how migration of Eclipse Launch Configrations (`ILaunchConfiguration`) works. In my dreams, I'd love to have the following:

1. My plugin, version 1.0, is used to create a Launch Configuration referencing file `something_1.0/foo`
2. The plugin is upgraded to version 2.0, which also deletes the file still referenced in all old launch configurations of the plugin
3. The old launch configurations are automatically upgraded so that `something_2.0/foo` is referenced instead of the non-existing `something_1.0/foo`

Step 3 sadly is the one that does not work, although I wrote and connected a corresponding implementation of `ILaunchConfigurationMigrationDelegate`. It seems the code is never executed.

When exactly are configurations migrated? According to the code, there is a `Migrate button`, which I cannot find. According to the documentation configurations might be migrated automatically. How is this triggered?

Thanks,
Carsten

Comment: The "Migrate..." button is in Window - Preferences - Run/Debug - Launching - Launch Configurations. After pressing it and picking my launch configurations, everything works as expected. The question remains: how can I migrate automatically? Or: How can I trigger migration?

Comment: I solved my original problem by not storing data inside the launch configs that need to be changed (instead, I just add them right before the actual launch). However, I still do not know how to migrate launch configurations without letting the user press the Migrate button.

Answer (score 0):

This [implementation of this interface](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/debug/core/ILaunchConfigurationMigrationDelegate.html) should be declared in extension point.

You can refer to JDT itself implementation **org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.JavaMigrationDelegate**.

Please note the launch shortcut specify the configuration type as the one defined via extension.

```
   <extension
     point="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchShortcuts">
  <shortcut
        class="org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaApplicationLaunchShortcut"
        description="%JavaLaunchShortcut.description"
        helpContextId="org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.shortcut_local_java_application"
        icon="$nl$/icons/full/etool16/java_app.gif"
        id="org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.localJavaShortcut"
        label="%JavaApplicationShortcut.label"
        modes="run, debug">
     <contextualLaunch>
       <enablement>
         <with variable="selection">
           <count value="1"/>
            <iterate>
             <and>
              <adapt type="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaElement">
                <test property="org.eclipse.jdt.core.isInJavaProject"/>
              </adapt>
              <or>
                <test property="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.hasMain"/>
                <test property="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.isContainer"/>
                <test property="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.isPackageFragment"/>
                <test property="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.isPackageFragmentRoot"/>
              </or>
             </and>
            </iterate>
           </with>
       </enablement>
     </contextualLaunch>
     <configurationType
           id="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.localJavaApplication">
     </configurationType>
     <description
           description="%RunJavaLaunchShortcut.description"
           mode="run">
     </description>
     <description
           description="%DebugJavaLaunchShortcut.description"
           mode="debug">
     </description>
  </shortcut>
```

Comment: The interface is implemented and used as an extension point. The only relevant difference I see to the JDT code is that I was missing a default constructor (which should be added automatically by the compiler)? Still, nothing happens, not even the constructor is invoked.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, I do not understand your changes (Missing words? Bad English?). Why are we talking about Launch Shortcuts now?